# Pass dynamic database to liquibase property

Tags: liquibase

My Liquibase property file looks like this

```
driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath: C:\\Program Files\\sqljdbc_10.2\\enu\\mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar
changeLogFile: .\\home_changeLog.xml
url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=home;integratedSecurity=false;trustServerCertificate=true;
username: user
password: password123
liquibase.hub.mode=off
```

I wanted to parametrise the database name used in the URL,  tried by changing the URL to

```
url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=${database};integratedSecurity=false;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

when I execute

```
liquibase --defaults-file="Home.properties"  updatesql -database="home2"
```

Liquibase raise the error below

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to
> jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=${database};integratedSecurity=false;trustServerCertificate=true;
> with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  The
> connection string contains a badly formed name or value.

If I execute

```
liquibase --defaults-file="Home.properties"  updatesql --database="home2"
```

> Unexpected argument(s): --database=home2

How can I parametrise the database name used in the URL? I would like to use the change log file rather than using different change log files for each environment.

Thanks

Comment: did you try with `--database=...` - I believe liquibase uses double-dashes for parameters.  If that fails, you can always use the `--url` parameters and pass the whole connection string instead (in quotes - i.e. `--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle"`).  If you do use the `--url` parameter, you might need to remove it from the config file (I am not sure)

Comment: @blurus, thanks. Yes tried. I get Unexpected argument(s):

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you tried.  The parameter above is straight out of their documentation so it should work.  See their docs: https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/working-with-command-parameters.html

Comment: I have updated the original qiestion

Comment: I suppose liquibase does not recognize the `--database` argument - closest thing you can do is pass the entire URL.  In fact, I cannot find this parameter in their documentation so it might not  be a valid one either (see: https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/command-parameters.html)

Comment: Perhaps schema name will suit your needs? `--liquibase-schema-name=<string>` (https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/liquibase-schema-name.html)